# What are the meanings of the line colors in Git log graph?

Tags: git

I use `git log --graph` to get a console log graph as below. What are the meanings of the line colors on the left side? I can see red, blue, green, yellow colors. I don't know if there are more. And I even noticed the lines are totally **broken** once, not in this graph.

[image]

But in TortoiseGit GUI, the line color seems less complex.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lines are there to simply represent your graph in a way that is at least visibly discerning.  The lines represent ancestry, and the asterisks represent individual commits.  The only time a line would be "broken" is if there is no known ancestry for a commit, like in the case of root commits or orphaned branches.

The colors themselves follow commits along a specific ancestry so that it's easier to see when a specific commit made its way into the repository.

If you have many branches, you'll get many colors (and many, many lines).